# Temporarily removing a python module

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to temporarily remove a python module from sys.modules so that I can import it as part of a test case (with various system functions mocked out) and then put it back again.  (Yes, that's a bit crazy and I'm probably going to end up restructuring the code instead *but* now I'm curious...)

I can remove the module and reimport it just fine but I can't seem to put it back to the original module once I'm finished.  (Maybe that's just not posible?)  Here's a test case that I wrote to test out the idea:

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_assumptions(self):
        import meta.common.fileutils as fu1
        del(sys.modules["meta.common.fileutils"])
        import meta.common.fileutils
        del(sys.modules["meta.common.fileutils"])
        sys.modules["meta.common.fileutils"] = fu1 # I hoped this would set the module back
        import meta.common.fileutils as fu2
        self.assertEqual(fu1, fu2)  # assert fails, fu2 is a new copy of module :-(
```

Can anyone suggest why it might be failing?

Edit, using pop() as suggested by one of the answers also fails:

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_assumptions(self):
        import meta.common.fileutils as fu1
        orig = sys.modules.pop("meta.common.fileutils")
        import meta.common.fileutils
        del(sys.modules["meta.common.fileutils"])
        sys.modules["meta.common.fileutils"] = orig 
        import meta.common.fileutils as fu2
        self.assertEqual(fu1, orig) # passes
        self.assertEqual(fu2, orig) # fails
        self.assertEqual(fu1, fu2)  # fails
```

Comment: What are `mod1` and `mod2`? Where are they defined?

Comment: Sorry, copy and paste error.  I've fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like the issue here has to do with packages.  In particular, for a module that lives in a package (eg `meta.common`), there are two ways to access it: via `sys.modules`, and via the parent package's dictionary (i.e., `meta.common.__dict__`).  It looks to me like the `import meta.common.fileutils as fu2` line is getting `fu2`'s value from `meta.common.__dict__`, and not from `sys.modules`.

So the solution: in addition to monkey-patching sys.modules, you should also monkey-patch the parent package.  I.e., add something like this:

```
>>> import meta.common
>>> meta.common.fileutils = fu1
```

right before the `sys.modules["meta.common.fileutils"] = fu1` line.

Answer (score 4):

The `sys.modules` structure is really *just* a Python `dict`. You can remove modules from it, and you can also *put them back in*.

Store the original module object in a local variable, using [`dict.pop()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) to both remove the module and return it:

```
orig = sys.modules.pop('meta.common.fileutils')
```

then, when it comes to restoring it, just put that object back into `sys.modules`:

```
sys.modules['meta.common.fileutils'] = orig
```

Comment: Doing that fails too, I've posted my updated code as an edit.